# Creating objects using the Class class

Tags: java

How do I instantiate an object using the Class class?

I would like to pass a Class object to a function and have that function return a new object of the class I pass in.

I will be doing casting after I get the object back. Also, are there any suggestions on design patterns for this sort of thing?

Here is some example pseudo code that shows what I want to do:

```
Class Animal {
    String name;
}

Class Cat extends Animal {
    boolean hasTail;
}
```

MAIN:

```
Class myClass = Cat.class;
Animal createAnimal(myClass) {
    return new myClass;
}
```

Edit:

Also, is there a way to cast within my function before returning the new instance or am I stuck with the default Object type?

```
return (myClass)myClass.newInstance();
```

Comment: What you want to achieve eerily resembles the Factory pattern. Check this thing out: http://www.allapplabs.com/java_design_patterns/factory_pattern.htm and annotate your question with the homework tag

Comment: @Perception No. But I'll take any resources you post and read up on it.

Comment: Fair enough. Here is the Javadoc for `java.lang.Class`. Pay particular attention to the `newInstance` method: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html

Comment: You can check which instance of myClass belongs to by if(myClass instanceOf Cat) {return new Cat()}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I will be doing casting after I get the object back.
>
> Also, is there a way to cast within my function before returning the new instance or am I stuck with the default Object type?

You don't need to do casting if you take advantage of generics.  Generics are described in relatively introductory detail [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/index.html)

Here is a java example derived from your psuedo code using generics and reflection:

```
public class ReflectionNewInstanceTest {

    static class Animal {
        String name;
    }

    static class Cat extends Animal { 
        boolean hasTail = true;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Animal a = createAnimal(Cat.class);
    }


    static <T extends Animal> T createAnimal(Class<T> clazz) throws Exception {
        return clazz.newInstance();
    }

}
```

As for patterns, any of the typical creational patterns should be looked at when you want to abstract away the creation of objects.  The simplest is probably just using a factory method.  The example I have above is just a general purpose factory method that doesn't really gain you much. Here is a pretty short list of patterns you should look up:

- Abstract factory pattern
- Factory method pattern
- Builder pattern
- Prototype pattern

Answer (score 6):

I suspect you want [`Class.newInstance()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#newInstance%28%29). Note that you'd call it with `Cat.class`, not `Cat.getClass()`.

Note that `newInstance()` will always try to call a parameterless constructor - if you need to pass any arguments, use [`getConstructors()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getConstructors%28%29) to find the constructors declared by that class, then invoke the appropriate one.

Comment: this will work only in the case that his Class has a no-args constructor (which seems to be the case currently), so +1

Comment: Say there were args... do I just put the parameters in the call? Ex. Class.newInstance(arg1,arg2)?

Comment: @Matthew: No, you call `getConstructors()`, find the appropriate one, then call `constructor.newInstance(arg1, arg2, ...)`

Comment: @baba is that for the single line function declaration and open brace? I had them on separate lines before. Mine wasn't kosher according to Java best practices am I right? Or is that just personal preference?

Comment: People would disagree, but I hear in C# separate lines are standard. It depends on the company and team you work in, you should fit in. I personally write code like 'an Egyptian'. Both methods are OK, but Oracle(Sun) prefer the Egyptian style: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-141999.html#216 Since you are using other people's code as well, which is mostly written in the same style as Sun's, it is a good idea for your code to also conform to those standards.

Answer (score 1):

You are probably looking for the [getConstructor()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getConstructor%28java.lang.Class%5B%5D%29) and the [newInstance()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Constructor.html#newInstance%28java.lang.Object%5B%5D%29) methods in Class, Constructor classes respectively.

If your constructor is guaranteed to have no arguments, you might also shorthand it and use [newInstance()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#newInstance%28%29) [in Class]